# Displaying marker with text in highchart gauge vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

i wanted to display a marker with text to shows a target in my highchart gauge. I have displayed the marker like the image below. I want to display a label beside the marker to show some text

[image: The]

i found some code online where we use datalabels but then the label is manually positioned using x,y coordinates. My data comes from a database so i cannot have a fixed position as the data can change anytime. The code is displayed below-

```
<template>
  <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";

export default {
  name: "CustomGuage",
  components: {
  highcharts: Chart
},
  props: ["data", "title", "name", "min", "max", "format", "text", "x", 
  "y","target"],
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
         type: "solidgauge",
         marginBottom: 190
      },

    title: {
      text: this.title,
      align: "left"
    },

    pane: {
      center: ["50%", "85%"],
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      size: 200,
      background: {
        innerRadius: "60%",
        outerRadius: "100%",
        shape: "arc"
      }
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      // plotBands: {
      //   from: 60,
      //   to: 61,
      //   zIndex: 10,
      //   color: "black",
      //   thickness: "45%",
      //   outerRadius: "105%",
      //   label: {
      //     text: this.text,
      //     align: "center",
      //      x: this.x,
      //      y: this.y
      //   }
      // },
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      stops: [
        [0.1, "#DF5353"], // green
        [0.5, "#DDDF0D"], // yellow
        [0.9, "#55BF3B"] // red
      ],
      //  minColor: '#DF5353',
      //   maxColor: '#55BF3B',
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickAmount: 2,
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: -1,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: this.name,
        data: this.data,
        dataLabels: {
          format: this.format
        }
      },
      {
        data: this.target, // value at where the marker is rendered
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
        type: "gauge",
        
        dial: {  // code that displays the marker
          baseLength: "100%",
          radius: "110%",
          rearLength: "-45%",
          
        },
      }
    ]
  }
 };
 },
watch: {
  data(newVal) {
    this.chartOptions.series[0].data = newVal;
   }
  }
 };
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to put a label beside the marker that would automatically display wherever the marker is placed depending on the data from the database without manually putting the position of the label

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to center the data label position by setting the `y` property which will be relative to your chart height or by setting the `dataLabels.verticalAlign` property to `bottom`.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-8gwky?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

```
dataLabels: {
  //y: -80,
  verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  borderWidth: 0,
  useHTML: true,
  format: '<div style="text-align:center">' +
    '<span style="font-size:25px">{y}</span><br/>' +
    '<span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">km/h</span>' +
    '</div>'
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.dataLabels.verticalAlign